# Where does Java store associated with object wait set?

Tags: java, jvm

Well, each JVM implementation may have a different strategy to layout objects and arrays in memory.

The **HotSpot JVM** uses a data structure called **Ordinary Object Pointers** (OOPS) to represent pointers to objects.
Each **oopDesc** describes the pointer with the following information:
One **mark word**
One, possibly compressed, **klass word**

***A mark word describes the object header***. ***The HotSpot JVM uses this word to store identity hashcode, biased locking pattern, locking information, and GC metadata.***

But I can't understated where associated with object **wait set** is stored.. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Reading https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/Synchronization may help